# how to get dynamic subdomain on nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, iis

I have a vps:

- client: 220.123.111.233 point to domain: mydomain.com
- server: has port 220.123.111.233:8080 point to mydomain.com:8080
  I want the client and server to point to this domain together: mydomain.com
  the server will drop the port and it will be like this:
- client: mydomain.com
- server: 12n2.mydomain.com (dynamic domain)
  i need help from everyone.
  thank's much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are too less information. Please show some code about what you have done and what issue you got. And how your domain and server set?